# Benchmarks for Hadoop Performance

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I wanted to know what are the "standard" ways to gather data in regards to a certain Hadoop cluster configuration, meaning, getting concrete evidence on how fast a certain cluster configuration runs like throughput, bandwidth and **anything else I should be considering**. I'm currently looking at and trying to understand TestDFSIO, but I can't help but think this isn't completely analyzing Hadoop performance (I read somewhere that it does not account for certain overhead).

If it helps, my current hadoop cluster setup is 2 servers, with KVMs on top of them, one with 2 VMs, and the other with 1 VM. I want to compare the performance of this configuration to a simpler hadoop config (w/o KVMs or VMs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other benchmarks, which, specifically TeraSort which will measure Your cluster shuffling performance, but I would not tell that they are too informative.
IMHO Profiling hadoop cluster is somewhat like profiling JVM - does not make much sense without concrete application. 
.
What I want to tell that perofrmance of hadoop cluster should be assessed in relation to some MR job you going to run on it. Some jobs will be IO bound and the rest of the system performance will be not relevant. Some will be CPU bound in Map Stage, and the rest is not important, etc..